# session in MVC-3(Razor-View Engine)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone tell me how to create Session Context in Mvc3 ? 
I am new in Mvc and want to know about How to create session and Syntaxes in Detail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To save session

```
@{ HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"] = "Test"; }
```

To fetch session

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["Session"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HttpContext` class to access `Session` and more. You will not need to instantiate a session, this happens automatically. All you need to do is reference it in your code.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["MyVariable"] = "Something"; 
@HttpContext.Current.Session["MyVariable"].ToString()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx